# Sorting a view basing on the value of a boolean field

Tags: views

I have a content type X. A view is used to display this content type (X), as a table. The content type has a field called "Preferred" which contains boolean values. I need to sort the table so that the "Preferred:true" items display at the top of the table.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

Add a new `Sort Criteria` sorter that sorts based on that field. Make sure it's at the top of your list of sort criteria.

If you don't want there to be a column for it in the table, click "exclude from display" in the field settings.

Comment: I tried that but, it doesn't work. I created a new Sort Criteria for Preferred. It sorts them together but, they are not at the top of the table.

Comment: and if my logic gene is in gear today, you'll want to sort descending so that all the 1's come first and then the 0's.

Comment: What exactly did you do when you tried it? What happened when you tried?

Comment: Okay. I added the Sort criteria and now it sorts correctly. But, is there anyway to sort the rest of the columns (that are not preferred true) to be alphabetical?

Comment: Actually, I just added another sort criteria to sort by title and everything works fine. Funny thing is, I tried the same thing earlier and it was not working.

Anyways, Thank You!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. If my answer was correct for what you wanted, even if you figured it out on your own, you might want to mark it "accepted" because then it tells other people who read the question that it is correct. And it also gives me rep points ;-)